# Why does x = 44 in this case?

Tags: c++, char, unsigned

```
unsigned char x = 0;
unsigned char y = 150;

x = 2 * y;

cout << "x: " << (int)x << endl; // returns 44
```

I understand that unsigned char meaning ASCII characters from 0 to 255 but i dont know why the x is printing our 44.

Does anyone have an ASCII chart i can follow?

Comment: It is an out of range conversion.

Comment: ASCII chart --> google

Comment: @ArdentCoder The the value during conversion is entirely in the representable range of `int`.

Comment: 2*150=300 and 300 - 256 = 44

Comment: 300 = 0x01 0x2c, only 0x2c is kept, 0x2c = 44

Comment: @KonradRudolph `x` is of type `unsigned char`, not `int`.

Comment: @ArdentCoder So by “conversion” you mean the implicit conversion from the promoted result of `2 * y` to `unsigned char`, rather than the explicit conversion in OP’s code?

Comment: @KonradRudolph Yes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I understand that unsigned char meaning ASCII characters from 0 to 255 but i dont know why the x is printing our 44.

Because 2*150 is 300 which is greater than 255. 300 is outside the representable values of unsined char on your system.

When the actual result of an arithmetic operation is outside of representable values of the target unsigned type, the result will be congruent with the actual result modulo the number of representable values. 44 is congruent with 300 modulo 256.

P.S. For signed integer types, if the result of an arithmetic operation is outside of representable values, the behaviour of the program will be undefined. Avoid at all costs.